# Magento 2.2.1 "Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller." Checkout using Authorized.net

Tags: magento2.2, authorize.net

Magento 2.2.1 : I have confirmed the transaction URLs, keys, and MD5 with Authorize.net. Transaction is processed and deducted from account.  Order is created within Magento, and emails are sent. However, the error message tells the customer at the time of the transaction that it has failed. When they attempt it again, it double charges them.

I have reviewed all logs and there is absolutely nothing being logged in system.log, error.log, debug.log with respect to the transaction.

Are there any other logs to review?

How can I properly inspect the browser session for response messages?

I have seen a similar issue in the past on a different website using 2.1 and the issue was with the transaction url. I corrected it to api2 and all worked well.

**UPDATE:**

I have switched to the Magento Blank theme and the issue still exists.

While viewing the console under the browser inspect, I see the following:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.<mydomain>.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect/x_invoice_num/000075321/success/1/controller_action_name/directpost_payment/is_secure/1/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Is this an issue with respect to what I am experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of frame options in:

```
app/etc/env.php
```

I resolved it by setting it to 'SAMEORIGIN':

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

I experineced the issue when set to 'DENY'.

Comment: Congrats! Please also consider to mark your answer as accepted if you believe it resolve your problem :)